# Transistor Amplifier Circuit (currents)

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, semiconductors, pnp

I have been studying transistor throughly this semester and I have always doubted this circuit schematic.
First of all is this schematic correct? What about current directions are they conventional? I can't understand why collector current is heading to the transistor isn't it supposed to be output current and why they are written in small letters when the are effected by the DC sources VEE and VCC

Sorry I'm very confused!

*Schematic is within the fullpage below*

Addition:
[image: full page]

Exam question:
[image: equestion]

Detailed answers : [Explanation](https://youtu.be/CZlMt2Ta68I)

Comment: What makes a circuit correct or incorrect ? Any circuit doing what it is supposed to do is "correct". It might not do what you expect when you don't understand it. This is a **Common Base** circuit. Stop doubting it because that prevents you from understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I'll work on it you are right.

Comment: Other than the question about arrow direction, I am still not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: @jonk it's not actually a question just an example. I'll upload a sample question I found on a previous exam.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I couldn't figure out if I had anything to say, or not. I see a lot of photocopied details and pretty much nothing from you except "confusion" and the arrow direction (which I think you understand already from answers given, if not otherwise.)

Comment: I'm not permitted to attach more than 2 links as I have less than 10 reputation. I deleted first cropped schematic and here it is. @jonk

Comment: @SerajSersawi That provides a context. So where are you getting stuck? Can you pick a question and show me where you get lost?

Comment: lack of community votes on my answer is his major issue... Ic polarity and ...Av gain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all is this schematic correct?

This circuit is a standard common-base amplifier using a PNP transistor.

If you wanted a D flip-flop, it's not correct.

If you wanted a PNP common-base amplifier, it is correct.

> What about current directions are they conventional?

Unless you're in the US Navy or somebody specifically mentions "electron current", you can safely assume that "current" means "conventional current".

> I can't understand why collector current is heading to the transistor isn't it supposed to be output current

Your text is probably using the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention). This means taking all device currents going in to the device. Using this convention simplifies calculating the power consumption of each device in the circuit.

If current is actually flowing out of the collector, you'll just find \$i_c < 0\$.

> why they are written in small letters when the are effected by the DC sources VEE and VCC

What small letters and upper-case letters mean is entirely a convention decided by each author. So you'll have to read your text to find out what is intended.

It is common to designate AC currents with lower-case letters. It may be that even though DC currents are present, the author wanted to discuss AC currents, so he indicated the AC currents on the diagram.

Comment: You are right about passive sign conv. I found ic to be negative. AC-related currents of voltages are in small letters in this textbook.

Comment: Please take a look at the full page, I see it as a complete mess, I hope you can clarify what is he doing for me. Thanks in advance sir!

Comment: @SerajSersawi, I agree it is a mess. Look for a better book. (Maybe you made a comment about Vcc < 0, then deleted it --- Given the way Vcc is defined in the diagram with + terminal at ground, and - terminal toward the PNP collector, Vcc must be positive (making voltage at the collector negative) for this circuit to work).

Comment: You may be confused by the assumption of using KCL convention for sum of all current into a node=0, but this convention is rarely used in BJT calculations as shown. We never think of collector currents as negative.   That's why I considered it wrong. Just positive from + to -.  So remember this in future.

Comment: yeah I was hesitant about it but it's right, I think I should see my lecturer but he barely answers else than a smile. I've searched youtube, allaboutelectronics and many other sites and I couldn't find one textbook talking about PNP BJT common base configuration. Anyways thank you all for your contributions I'll try to handle this mess. @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 , The Photon.

Comment: Found some explanation: https://youtu.be/CZlMt2Ta68I

Answer (score 1):

The arrow is wrong for \$ i_C\$ if you consider DC current flows from + to - and even ac non inverting current.

But the schematic is correct for a Common Base PNP amplifier with input via emitter (low Zin= {(Rbe/hFE) // Re} and Zout=Rc)

\$ i_C\$ flows from + to -ve same as \$i_E\$

Comment: Thank you! Please take a look at the full page I attached.

Comment: which part of your homework do you not understand?

Comment: Rc=V(Rc)/Ic (where Ic=Ie*.99) = 10V/(2mA*.99)

Comment: This is not a homework, I have a problem with sign conventions in this schematic.

Comment: If Av=gain=Rc/Rs as long as Rs >rE and Re is neglected as it is for DC bias and Rs is usually selected << Re while Rc is computed above and i(Rs)-0.6mA (pk) . Dont confuse DC bias  current with AC gain.

Comment: I told you the sign of DC current is wrong. You can take my word for it , or not.. Current flows thru Re and Rc in the same direction, + to -.  Tell the author to correct it. or ask others to concur or deny by upvotes or downvotes, if they are willing , that is...

Comment: Do you mean iE should be IE and same for iC but IC is in the opposite direction of what is shown?

Comment: correct. the arrow is wrong and Ie=Ib+Ic  almost same which is denoted by alpha=0.99=Ic/Ie meaning hFE=  Ic/Ib =100.. I agree the question is poorly written and the diagram is poorly shown so I sympathize with your confusion. But it is trying to get you to think from a different perspective. like sideways or upside down and even wrong direction (which I am sure was a oops)

Comment: The arrow can't be wrong --- it's a definition given as part of the problem. The value of the DC current will simply turn out to be negative once you do the math. OP, you should be prepared to take currents defined whichever way somebody chooses and keep your math consistent with those definitions. Someday you'll need to solve a circuit where it isn't obvious what way the current will end up flowing, and you'll need to be able to solve that circuit also.

Comment: Well I disagree, but no matter, the arrow only adds confustion and nowhere are -Ic values relevant to the question.   It's an error.  Even you and I make mistakes, but I correct mine.  By convention we always say current flows from + to - in electronics and this violates that convention.

Comment: An equally common convention (more common in school) is the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) which says that device terminal currents are **in** to the device. As long as you keep the math consistent with your definition of current direction, though, it shouldn't matter at all what convention you use or even if you just guess directions of currents randomly.

Comment: Sure KCL does this but to apply to the Ebers Moll model of a CB amp only adds confusion, I could call it an academic and non-practical approach or a minor error, but obvious proof to my claim is his confusion.